# Is the expression "confound it" a euphemism?

Tags: expressions

I've sometimes heard people say, 'confound it'. So, I'm wondering whether this is considered a euphemism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extent this is a matter of personal opinion.  I think "confound it" is just another mild interjection to express frustration, like "darn!" or "drat!" or "rats!"  Meanwhile, a *euphemism* is a "nice" word that is used in place of a "not nice" word, such as saying "darn it!" instead of "damn it!" (which in some social situations would be considered an unspeakable *expletive*).

It's possible that some people say "confound it" as a mild substitute for a stronger expletive such as "fuck it" ... but no one I know does this.